# Prove an equality between dimensions of kernels

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation, inner-products

Let $V$ be a inner product space over field $\mathbb{R}$ with $\dim(V)<\infty$, and $T\in \text{Hom}(V,V)$.
I'm trying to prove:$$\dim(\ker T)=\dim(\ker T^*)=\dim(\ker TT^*)$$
Also, as a conclusion from it I need to show that: $$\text{Im}(T)=\text{Im}(TT^*)$$
Note: $T^*$ is the adjoint operator (aka:  Hermitian conjugate)

I would be very happy to receive some guidance for it, detailed as much as possible, since this subject is new to me and I am really struggling with it. Thanks!

Comment: What is $\,T^*\;$ ? If it is the usual adjoint of $\,T\,$ then you have here an inner product linear space, not *only* a vector space.

Comment: You are correct of course, my mistake, I'm sorry. I edited the question above. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for a quick addressing, but note that adjoint operator=Hermitian conjugate if we're assuming we work with an orthonormal basis, which of course we can assume safely.

Comment: Thank you! I'm currently working on solving it.

Comment: @DonAntonio I got stuck in proving that $dimkerT=dimkerT^{*}T$ and that $imTT^*\subseteq imT$ , I would really appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: we have that $$w\in\text{Im}\,TT^*\implies\,\exists\,v\in V\;\;s.t.\;\;w=TT^*v=T\left(T^*v\right)\in\text{Im}\,T\;\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you I understand that now, what about $dimkerTT^{*}=dimkerT$ ?

Comment: did you read my answer? It is there...:)

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm truly sorry! I meant $dimkerT=dimkerTT^{*}$ , I edited the comment above.

Comment: This part was in "..." in your proof and I didn't got the idea of it, if you can give me some guidance in this it will be great :)

Comment: we can deduce from (1)-(2) in my answer that $\,\dim\text{Im}\,T=\dim\text{Im}\,TT^*\,$ , and from here we can deduce the respective equaluty for the dimensions of the respective kernel using the dimension theorem...

Comment: @DonAntonio I need to prove it without use of the conclusion $dimImT=dimImTT^*$. Is there any other way to prove: $dimkerT=dimkerT^*$ or $dimkerT=dimkerTT^*$ (maybe using similar way to how you proved $dimkerT^{*}=dimkerTT^{*}$ using aggregation from both sides) I am really desperate over here!

Comment: First @ashley, I can't see why would you *have* to prove that without that identity **which you're proving** . Second, I'm not sure if there's another way: the one I propose was so simple for me as it follows from what I did before in that answer that I didn't thibnk of other ways...

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you very much I sorted it out!

Comment: Way to go, @user86404 . Now just remember than besides "accepting" the answer that looks the best for you, you can **always** upvote as many answers as you like (including the accepted one) if you think they ahelped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$$w\in \ker T^*\implies T^*w=0\implies TT^*w=T(0)=0\implies$$

$$\implies w\in\ker TT^*\implies \dim\ker T^*\le\dim\ker TT^*$$

OTOH, we also have (since $\;T^{**}=T\;$):

$$w\in\ker TT^*\implies TT^*w=0\implies\;\forall\,v\in V\;,\;0=\langle v\,,\,TT^*w\rangle=\langle T^*v\,,\,T^*w\rangle\implies$$

$$\implies \;\;\text{in particualr, we get for}\;\;v=w:\;\;\langle T^*w\,,\,T^*w\rangle=0\implies$$

$$\implies T^*w=0\implies w\in\ker T^*\implies \dim\ker TT^*\le\dim\ker T^*$$

Now just put $\,S=T^*\;$ and apply the above for $\;S\;$:

$$\dim\ker T=\dim \ker T^{**}=\dim\ker S^*=\dim \ker SS^*=\dim\ker T^*T^{**}=\dim\ker T^*T\;\ldots$$

Finally, use the dimension theorem:

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;\dim V=\dim\ker T+\dim\text{Im}T=\dim\ker TT^*+\dim\text{Im}\,T\\
(2)&\;\;\dim V=\dim\ker TT^*+\dim\text{Im}\,TT^*\;\;\ldots\end{align*}$$

Note: you **still** need to complete some stuff above!

Answer (score 1):

If you prove that $\dim\ker T=\dim\ker TT^*$, you have that
$$
\dim(\operatorname{im}T)=\dim V-\dim(\ker T)=
\dim V-\dim(\ker TT^*)=\dim(\operatorname{im}TT^*).
$$
But $\operatorname{im}T\supseteq\operatorname{im}TT^*$, so they're equal.

Let's tackle the other problem. If $v\in\ker TT^*$, then 
$$
0=\langle v,0\rangle=\langle v,TT^*v\rangle=
\langle T^*v,T^*v\rangle
$$
so that $T^*v=0$. Hence $\ker TT^*\subseteq\ker T^*$. On the other hand, it's obvious that $\ker T^*\subseteq\ker TT^*$. Therefore $\ker TT^*=\ker T^*$.

Now recall that the ranks of $T$ and $T^*$ are equal to conclude that $\dim\ker T=\dim\ker ^*$ and you're done.

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried to prove why: $imTT^*\subseteq imT$ and I'm really struggling with it, can you help a little more?
Thanks!

Comment: @ashley-59mr If $w=TT^*(v)\in\operatorname{im}TT^*$, then $w=T(T^*(v))$, so $w\in\operatorname{im}T$. It's a general fact: if $F\colon U\to V$ and $G\colon V\to W$ are linear maps, then $\operatorname{im}GF\subseteq\operatorname{im}G$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! Can you help me with proving that: $dimkerTT^{*}=dimkerT$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $V$ is a vector space with an inner product. Then $\langle Tv,w\rangle = \langle v,T^* w \rangle$ for all $v,w\in V$. Now, $v\in\ker T$ if and only if $\langle Tv,w\rangle=0$ for all $w\in V$ if and only if $\langle Tv,Tv\rangle=0$. Try to use this to show that $\ker T = \ker T^* T$ (not only that the dimensions match).

For the conclusion try to prove that $\ker T = (\textrm{im } T^*)^\perp$.